# AutoMapper with nested objects and container class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I'm developing an API with .NET core and using AutoMapper.

all the API responses will be wrapped with a data element in the JSON response like below example

**GET User**

```
{
  "data" {
       "id" : 1,
       "user_name": "abc"
       "countryr" : {
         "id" : 1348,
         "code" : "USA"
        } 
   }
}
```

So we have an entity for `User` and `Country`

```
  public partial class User
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public virtual Country country { get; set; }

    }  

  public partial class Country
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code{ get; set; }
    }
```

To map entities to DTO we have below reponseDTO

```
 public class GetUserDTO {
      public User data {get; set;} // To wrap reponse with data
    }

 public class UserDto {
    public int id {get; set;}
    public String user_name {get; set;}
    public Country country {get; set;}
    }

 public class CountryDto  {
    public int id {get; set;}
    public String code {get; set;}
   }
```

As per my understanding , I should map the entity User to the `UserDTO` and Country entity to `CountryDTO` but what about `GetUserDTO` class itself? it basically contains other entities so the class itself cannot be mapped to anything it acts like a container.

So below what I did so far which is not correct

```
public class UserProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {

        CreateMap<User, GetUserDTO>();
        CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
        .ForMember(userDto => userDto.user_name, map => map.MapFrom(user => user.FirstName))
        CreateMap<Country, CountryDto>();


    }
}
```

Json response

```
{
  "data" : null
}
```

What to do for such situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not refer your entity classes in your DTO classes. You might want to change the DTO as below.

```
public class GetUserDTO {
  public UserDto data {get; set;} // To wrap reponse with data
}
public class UserDto {
  public int id {get; set;}
  public string user_name {get; set;}
  public CountryDto country {get; set;}
} 
public class CountryDto  {
  public int id {get; set;}
  public string code {get; set;}
```

}

And then in the Mapper profile, you need to explicitly map each property as cases are different(AutoMapper will map without explicity map if the names are exactly the same. In your example, there is a case difference)

And then remove the below line from the MapperProfile as there is no mapping from the User class to GetUserDTO class. This is the reason you are not getting any output.

```
CreateMap<User, GetUserDTO>();
```

While getting the data, you should create a new instance of GetUserDTO class and set the property "data" from the result of mappaing of the User object.

This will get you the output.

Comment: Thank you ! It's working . is it a good practice though? or do you have any suggestions

Comment: If you are doing the mapping in the controller, then you dont really need the GetUserDTO  class, you can use an anonymous object to return the data. If your are returning the GetUserDTO from your data access then this should be fine